# What is the difference between sheen, lustre and gloss

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I have referred to dictionaries, all of the three words express the meaning of something having a smooth and gentle brightness on its surface. So whether they are interchangeable or have subtle distinctions in there?

Answer (score 2):

Yes all the three are related to brightness and light but there is a subtle distinction between all the three. The very basic meanings of the following:
*Sheen* a soft lustre on a surface.
*Lustre* a gentle sheen or soft glow.
*Glow* to give out steady light without flame.

Lustre and Sheen refer to the state or quality of shining by reflecting light where as Glow can also refer to give off light from heat or to emit light as if heated.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. As you said, glow is sort of shed from fire, but what I got from dictionaries is gloss is different from glow. Do you have any idea of the distinctions when coming to gloss.@Sri9911